# How to merge two join queries

Tags: sql-server, join, merge

I need to display all the no of staff, doctors and patient in a each department..

I have tried this query to display  no of staff, doctors and it is works properly

```
ALTER view vwDisplay
AS
    select 
        dpt.Department_ID, dpt.Department_Name,
        num_of_doc, num_of_staff, No_of_Patient
    from 
        Department dpt
    join 
        (select 
             count(*) as num_of_doc, Department_ID 
         from 
             Doctor_Main 
         group by 
             Department_ID) dct on dpt.Department_ID = dct.Department_ID
    join 
        (select 
             count(*) as num_of_staff, Department_ID 
         from 
             Other_Staff 
         group by
             Department_ID) stf on stf.Department_ID = dpt.Department_ID
```

and I also need to display no of patient in each department. But there are no relationship between department and patient, doctor is only works for one department..

This query I used to display no of patient for each doctor

```
select count(*) as No_of_Patient, Doctor_Main.Doctor_ID
from Patients_Main
inner join Doctor_Main on Patients_Main.Doctor_ID = Doctor_Main.Doctor_ID
group by Doctor_Main.Doctor_ID
```

now I need to merge these two, when I execute this query as follows

```
ALTER view vwDisplay
as
select dpt.Department_ID,dpt.Department_Name,num_of_doc,num_of_staff,No_of_Patient
from Department dpt
    join (select count(*) as num_of_doc,Department_ID from Doctor_Main GROUP  BY Department_ID) dct
    on dpt.Department_ID = dct.Department_ID

    join (select count(*) as num_of_staff,Department_ID from Other_Staff GROUP  BY Department_ID) stf
    on stf.Department_ID = dpt.Department_ID

    --join (select count(*) as No_of_Patient,Doctor_ID from Patients_Main GROUP  BY Doctor_ID) dcth
    --on dcth.Doctor_ID = Doctor_Main.Doctor_ID


    select count(*) as No_of_Patient,Doctor_Main.Doctor_ID
    from Patients_Main
    inner join Doctor_Main on Patients_Main.Doctor_ID = Doctor_Main.Doctor_ID
    group by Doctor_Main.Doctor_ID
```

This error occurs:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

What can I do for this problem? Or do you have any other solution to do this?

Comment: View is still a *relational* object, it has rows and columns of defined types.

Comment: You have `Department_ID` on the `Doctors_Main`, so you should be able to Group by Department and get the patient count. Uncomment the join to getting the Patient count, but instead of `Doctor_ID`, Group by `Department_ID`. In the inner select, join to `Doctors_Main` to get the `Department_ID`

Comment: @WEI_DBA can you give me sample code .coz i confused with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you can try this.

```
ALTER view vwDisplay
as
select dpt.Department_ID,dpt.Department_Name,num_of_doc,num_of_staff,No_of_Patient
from Department dpt
    join (select count(*) as num_of_doc,Department_ID from Doctor_Main GROUP  BY Department_ID) dct
    on dpt.Department_ID = dct.Department_ID

    join (select count(*) as num_of_staff,Department_ID from Other_Staff GROUP  BY Department_ID) stf
    on stf.Department_ID = dpt.Department_ID

    join (select count(*) as No_of_Patient,DM.Department_ID from Patients_Main PM
          join Doctors_Main DM ON PM.Doctor_ID = DM.Doctor_ID GROUP  BY DM.Department_ID) dcth
    on dcth.Department_ID = dpt.Department_ID
```